# RTL8821CE driver not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 22.04

```bash
Kernel: 5.15.0-53-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
```

```bash
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: f6:6e:74:95:80:a5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-53-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=172.20.6.135 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:31 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:e0:4c:89:28:71
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.15.0-53-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:67 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
  *-usb:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
       vendor: ICS Advent
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:4
       logical name: enx00e04c534458
       version: 1.01
       serial: 00:e0:4c:53:44:58
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: usb-1.10 ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=dm9601 driverversion=5.15.0-53-generic duplex=full firmware=Davicom DM96xx USB 10/100 Ether ip=192.168.10.69 link=yes maxpower=120mA multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlxd03745e8e1bb
       serial: d0:37:45:e8:e1:bb
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu driverversion=5.15.0-53-generic ip=192.168.31.69 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

```bash
$ dkms status
# Nothing
```

```bash
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```bash
$ cat /etc/modules/interfaces
cat: /etc/modules/interfaces: Not a directory
```

```bash
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```bash
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf
# modprobe information used for DKMS modules
#
# This is a stub file, should be edited when needed,
# used by default by DKMS.
```

```bash
$ ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms
ls: cannot access '/lib/modules/5.15.0-53-generic/updates/dkms': No such file or directory
```

```bash
$ lsmod | grep 8821
rtw88_8821ce           16384  0
rtw88_8821c            94208  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_pci              32768  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_core            258048  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8821c
```

```bash
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enx00e04c534458  no wireless extensions.

wlxd03745e8e1bb  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MobinNet5-301-1"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:AD:D5:76:B5:5A   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=75/100  Signal level=-48 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
outline-tun0  no wireless extensions.

tun0      no wireless extensions.
```

I had 21.10 and one day Wi-Fi stopped working, after upgrade to 22.04 still not working (I hoped the upgrade would solve the problem).

[image]
[Wireless Info Script Result](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mT9j3HhckH/)

[image]

Comment: It says disabled, what results for `rfkill list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 3):

**Remove unnecessary DKMS modules...**

`sudo dkms remove mt7612u/1.0 --all`

`sudo dkms remove rtl8188fu/1.0 --all`

`dkms status` should now show...

```
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox/6.1.32, 5.15.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Confirm no unnecessary .ko files...**

`ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`

then `reboot`.

**Select DKMS module below and reboot...**

[image]

**If for some reason you can't select the DKMS driver...**

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

WiFi works when booted to a Ubuntu Live USB. Reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: After reboot, its change DISABLED to UNCLAIMED. Removed from `ip a` and the `rfkill list` only show Bluetooth

Comment: Please update your question with current output of (leave the old output there): `dkms status`, `sudo lshw -C network`, updated screenshot of Software & Updates Additional Drivers tab, `cat /etc/modules/interfaces`, and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Let me know when you got them for me to review.

Comment: @Fakhamatia And `cat /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf`, and disable VPN.

Comment: @Fakhamatia comment out "blacklist rtw88_8821ce" in /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf and reboot. Also show me `ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms`.

Comment: @Fakhamatia Is it working now? If not, is Secure Boot disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: @Fakhamatia Show me `lsmod | grep 8821`.

Comment: @Fakhamatia Where did you go?

Comment: no, not working. Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: @Fakhamatia We'll have to play with it a bit to discover why it's still not working. Please be patient. Undo the comment change we made in /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf, make it read "blacklist rtw88_8821ce". Then reboot. Then show me `lsmod | grep 8821` again. Then do `sudo modprobe rtl8821ce` and show me any output.

Comment: @Fakhamatia Then try `sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up`

Comment: First, I comment blacklist and then reboot and then `sudo modprobe rtl8821ce` and then `sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up`, Not working. I update `rfkill list` and add `ip a` and others

Comment: @Fakhamatia Show me `iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep -i ssid` and `iwlist wlp3s0 freq`.

Comment: `iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep -i ssid` show nothing.

Comment: @Fakhamatia It should be working now. It looks like it's connected to some network on channel 1. How many wireless networks are normally in your area? What channel is your router set to? Is this a desktop machine? Check the antenna wires to assure they are properly connected. Re-seat the card in its slot.

Comment: In this area about 5 wireless networks. Yes, is this AMD mini desktop. My wireless networks it's OK. Wireless driver one day stop finding networks.

Comment: @Fakhamatia You may have a hardware problem. That's why I need you to check the antenna wires, and re-seat the card in its slot. Find out why bluetooth is soft blocked. Review your keyboard shortcuts, as a function key might have put it into airplane mode, or disabled the wireless (doubtful). Check the WiFi settings panel and confirm that the OFF/ON switch at the top of the panel is in the ON position.

Comment: @Fakhamatia Are there any physical buttons on the outside of the AMD box that can effect the wireless?

Comment: @Fakhamatia Last option... boot to your Ubuntu Live 22.04 USB and see if WiFi works there.

Comment: Bluetooth is soft blocked because I turn off from settings. I boot Ubuntu Live, and it's found 7 wireless networks around me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136188/discussion-between-heynnema-and-fakhamatia).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. After upgrading Ubuntu 20.05 to Ubuntu 22.04, wifi stop working. Removing rtl8821ce-dkms as suggested and deleting rtw88_8821ce from blacklist worked for me. Using HP Pavilion 15-cw1005la.

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1
```

After this command, rtw88_8821ce is removed automatically from /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf. Then

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Error! The module/version combo: rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 is not located in the DKMS tree

Comment: Please post `dkms status`

Comment: `dkms status` is show nothing

Comment: Then rtl8821ce has been already removed. Please post `cat /etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf` and `lsmod | grep 8821`

Comment: # modprobe information used for DKMS modules
#
# This is a stub file, should be edited when needed,
# used by default by DKMS
=========================================
rtw88_8821ce           16384  0
rtw88_8821c            94208  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_pci              32768  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_core            258048  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8821c

Comment: That's correct. You have wifi modules loaded. Please post `iwconfig`

Comment: Kernel driver works perfectly on my computer. I don't use dkms. Kernel 5.17.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The issue appears when upgrading from Ubuntu 20, which kernel doesn't support rtl8821ce, so dkms module was installed. After upgrading to Ubuntu 22 you need to remove dkms module in order get wifi working again. I'm using kernel 5.15 on Ubuntu 22

Comment: I had 21.10 and one day Wi-Fi stopped working, after upgrade to 22.04 still not working (I hoped the upgrade would solve the problem). I update logs in question.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine this driver required to be self signed which means a password has to be entered MOK at install on linux then entered at reboot in the BIOS so it get accepted by the kernel. I did it and now it works.

The issue occurred after upgrading the BIOS firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.4.3. `rtl8821ce-dkms` did not work. So I removed it.

1.

- to check
  `sudo dkms status`
  #rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1: added
- to remove
  `sudo apt remove rtl8821ce-dkms`
  #Deleting module rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 completely from the DKMS tree.

2.Сomment out lines started with **blacklist**  if they exist.
`nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
# wifi problem
# instead try install sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential rtl8821ce-dkms 
#blacklist 8821ce
#blacklist rtw88
#blacklist rtw88_8821ce
#blacklist rtw88_8821c
#blacklist rtw88_pci
#blacklist rtw88_core
```

3.Open software updater => settings=> `additional drivers` tab
check option **don't use the device** for
**Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**

4.`reboot`