# Yet Another Issue with the infamous RTL8821CE

Tags: drivers, 20.04, realtek-wireless

After hours of testing and retesting, I'm about to give up on installing my RTL8821CE under any flavour of Linux available. I've tested many distros, but the only place where this driver works straight out of the box, is under W10 and W11. I'm using focal with KDE in case this is relevant in any case. Kernel version 5.15.0-46.

I've been reading hundreds of answers around, and I cannot find one that is less useful than the next. None scratch a possible solution to me unfortunatelly.

What I have already tried:

1. First with default Ubuntu driver rtl8821ce-dkms blacklisting rw88_8821ce.
2. Second with default kernel driver rtw88_8821ce blacklisting rtl8821ce
3. Third, with a manually compiled github driver from tomaspinho 8821ce blacklisting both rtl8821ce and rtw88_8821ce

The only relevant message for rtl8821ce:

```
rtl8821ce: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
rtl8821ce: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

With tomaspinho driver `8821ce` happens exactly the same

So far, so bad, nothing worked.

I can confirm that when I do `lsmod | grep cfg80211` I only see two drivers: wl and the one that is not blacklisted from the above.

What I've done already apart from this?

[RTL8821CE driver not working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407357/rtl8821ce-driver-not-working-on-ubuntu-22-04)

[WHY RTL8821CE or WIFI is Removed during Kernel Update on 20.04.4 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401475/why-rtl8821ce-or-wifi-is-removed-during-kernel-update-on-20-04-4-lts)

- `rfkill list` doesn't show anything of wireless, only ID 0 for Bluetooth.
- `dkms status` show the dkms driver in place, example `rtl8821ce, 5.5.2.1 5.15.0-46...: installed`
- `lshw -C network` shows the network device, UNCLAIMED

Some extra considerations:

1. Secureboot is OFF
2. I've set `pci=noaer` for in `/etc/default/grub` `GRUB_CMD_LINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (I've heard that advanced error reporting could couse trouble with this driver)

I don't know what else to do. I think I have tried out all the solutions in the market. I hope I could find someone that could provide some light to this darkness :)

UPDATE 1:

I think I've found some light: forgot to check dmesg specifically on rtw88_8821ce driver and here I find this issues:

```
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: Firmware version 24.8.0, H2C version 12
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: mac power on failed
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to power on mac
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: failed to setup chip information
rtw_8821ce: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -114
```

In one of the two threads I mentioned above, the solution with almost the same kernel version as mine (5.15.0-42 and mine is 5.15.0-46), they used the rtw88_8821ce to make wireless connection work.

So basically I think that the other two options (rtl8821ce and the very old 8821ce from tomaspinho) will never do the trick.

UPDATE 2:

Now this has opened a new world of opportunities to solve this

First things first, I've found that this chipset is slighty "evolved" compared to old ones (at least firmware-wise). I'm talking about a Realtek 8821CE RFE Type 6 which is not the same as the popular ones I read on this forums.

I'm checking the Linux kernel lists relating to RTW88_8821CE driver, because I have to say that both Launchpad RTL driver and obviously, the super-old tomaspinho driver are never going to work with this new chipset (unless they plan to update).

UPDATE 3:

After a lot of testing which included compiling Linux Kernel 6.0-rc7 and testing multiple drivers we have gotten to the conclusion that the problem can rely on the motherboard. After checking the motherboard specs in Linux, we have found that most fields are "Default" and not set. Like some kind of weird underdog motherboard that has being created specifically for this laptop without any kind of Linux in mind.

I have officially desisted with this laptop, and I will return it to Windows and give it away to some family member. I will probably look into a cheap Chromebook which probably will be 101% compatible with any other Linux distribution, since Chrome OS is basically the dumb member of the Linux family.

Comment: Please try the dmesg | grep 8821 command NOT lsmod | cfg80211 read the output for Error: Driver 'rtl8821ce' is already registered, aborting... type messages per the [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401475/why-rtl8821ce-or-wifi-is-removed-during-kernel-update-on-20-04-4-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1) and then blacklist any in error.  In the end the one that worked for me was the one that came with the kernel specifically - rtw88_8821ce.  Then remove the others via dkms as @chili555 suggested.

Comment: I'm currently on 5.15.0.48 still working - I will update my question with this.

Comment: @xtrchessreal as I comment in the bottom I think the issue is the firmware of my chipset, comparatively to yours (v9.X as I can remember), mine is above v20). There are significant changes. I've found some information in the RTW implementation that points out that there have released a patch for the latest 5.18 kernel, which I don't have an I would not probably have neither with focal or even with jammy. So basically I must figure out how to patch just the RTL module (and keep on patching for succesive kernel updates, that will be a pain in the ass)

Comment: I'm 99% confident that here is the solution
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7e062cda7d90543ac8c7700fc7c5527d0c0f22ad/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/rtw8821c.c

Now I have to understand how to 
a) Download my current kernel sources (to check diffs)
b) Patch the wifi kernel file
c) Recompile my kernel

This is going to be badass and pain-in-the-ass.

Comment: linux from scratch? half joking. compliments on your question's presentation. what doesn't kill us makes us stronger.

Comment: try
echo "options 8821ce wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8821ce.conf
and reboot

Comment: I use rtw_8821ce. Ubuntu 22.04.1. Kernel 5.17. No problems with Bluetooth and Wifi. On Ubuntu 20.04 with the same driver, 5.10 kernel I had problems with Bluetooth. I found that linux-firmware package plays important role.